# Election Algorithms - A ring algorithm

Tags: algorithm, distributed-system

I been reading about Election algorithms in Distributed Systems. I read about the Bully Algorithm and understood it. I came across `A Ring Algorithm`, read about it an understood how it conducts the election but I could not understand how does it handle a situation when two processes `2` and `5` simultaneously discover that the coordinator `7`is not functioning.

> Each of these builds an ELECTION message and start circulating it.Eventually, both messages will go all the way around,and both `2` and `5` will convert them to COORDINATOR message, with exactly the same number and in the same order.

Who is going to be the coordinator (`2`or `5`) and why according to this algorithm?

Comment: @If both 2 and 5 initiate the algorithm,at the same time the Coordinatore will always be 5(larger id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say 2 and 5 discover that coordinator is not functioning, then both will initiate election algorithm.

Since the **ring is unidirectional**, the messages can only travel in one direction. The election message of 2 will reach 5 and election message of 5 will reach 2.

But interesting point is that whenever a node receives election message it appends its id to that message.Also when a node receives its own election message, it chooses the **node with largest id to be new coordinator** which will be 5 in both election message.

Hence 5 will become the coordinator and send the coordinator message.

Comment: That is it! I been missing this --->" it chooses node with largest id to be new coordinator", now I understand, thanks very much.